# How to make this def for loading tiff files work?

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, scikit-image

I would like to cut my code into chunk so I don't have to run everything at once. Can someone point me in the direction as to why this works:

```py
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
    
filename = input("Enter file name\n")
img = io.imread(f"images/{filename}.tif", as_gray=True)
img = np.array(img).astype(np.float32)
```

but this doesn't work?

```py
from skimage import io
import numpy as np

def loadfile():
    filename = input("Enter file name\n")
    img = io.imread(f"images/{filename}.tif", as_gray=True)
    img = np.array(img).astype(np.float32)
```

Comment: Can you clarify `this doesn't work`? E.g. it looks like you are not calling the function `loadfile` at all.

Comment: Well, the second version defines a function that never gets called - and doesn't return the loaded image, so it would be useless even if it was called.

Comment: So it's not really related to skimage at all....

Comment: @jtlz2, I think I just rolled back a formatting edit you made. _Either_ triple-backtick lines _or_ four-space indents should be used for code formatting, not both at once -- see how starting from revision 2 the code was excessively indented.